# add callback for separate g_main_loop

Tags: loops, glib

I have some misunderstanding about how `GMainLoop` work.
Main thing - API which add some callbacks into `g_main_loop` (like `g_timeout_add_seconds()`) don't take pointer to which loop you want to add that callback.

It looks like you add callback's for all `g_main_loop` instances.
Even if you have not yet created. Simple example for this:

```
#include <glib.h>

gboolean callback(gpointer data)
{
  static guint16 i=0; 
  g_print("Iter=%"G_GUINT16_FORMAT"\n",i++);
  if(i%5==0){
    g_print("try to stop loop1\n");
    g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop*)data);
  }
  return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
  GMainLoop* loop1 = NULL;
  GMainLoop* loop2 = NULL;
  loop1 = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  g_timeout_add_seconds(1, callback,loop1);

  loop2 = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  g_print("run loop1\n");
  g_main_loop_run(loop1);
  g_free(loop1);
  g_print("run loop2\n");
  g_main_loop_run(loop2);
  g_free(loop2);
  return 0;
}
```

Result is:

```
run loop1
Iter=0
Iter=1
Iter=2
Iter=3
Iter=4
try to stop loop1
run loop2
Iter=5
Iter=6
Iter=7
Iter=8
Iter=9
try to stop loop1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is it possible add `callback()` to `loop1`, and don't add it to `loop2`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation for [`g_idle_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add), [`g_idle_add_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add-full), [`g_timeout_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add), or [`g_timeout_add_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-full) will tell you:

> This internally creates a main loop source using [`g_timeout_source_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-source-new) and attaches it to the main loop context using [`g_source_attach()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach). You can do these steps manually if you need greater control.

Note that it says it attaches the source to the main loop **context**—*i.e.*, a [`GMainContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainContext), not a [`GMainLoop`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainLoop).  When you create your `GMainLoop` instances you're passing `NULL` for the first argument.  According to the [`the g_main_loop_new() documentation`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-new), that argument is

> a [`GMainContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainContext) (if `NULL`, the default context will be used).

So, you are creating two main loops, both using the same context (which is the default context).

To get the result I think you're expecting, you should do something like:

```c
#include <glib.h>

gboolean callback(gpointer data)
{
  static guint16 i=0; 
  g_print("Iter=%"G_GUINT16_FORMAT"\n",i++);
  if(i%5==0){
    g_print("try to stop loop1\n", data);
    g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop*)data);
  }
  return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
  GMainContext* con1 = NULL;
  GMainContext* con2 = NULL;
  GMainLoop* loop1 = NULL;
  GMainLoop* loop2 = NULL;
  GSource* source1 = NULL;

  con1 = g_main_context_new ();
  con2 = g_main_context_new ();

  loop1 = g_main_loop_new (con1, FALSE);
  loop2 = g_main_loop_new (con2, FALSE);

  source1 = g_timeout_source_new_seconds (1);
  g_source_set_callback (source1, callback, loop1, NULL);
  g_source_attach (source1, con1);

  // We don't need the GMainContext anymore—the loop has an internal
  // reference so we'll drop ours.
  g_main_context_unref (con1);
  con1 = NULL;

  // Ditto for the GSource
  g_source_unref (source1);
  source1 = NULL;

  g_main_context_unref (con2);
  con2 = NULL;

  g_print("run loop1\n");
  g_main_loop_run(loop1);
  // Use g_main_loop_unref, not g_free
  g_main_loop_unref(loop1);
  loop1 = NULL;

  g_print("run loop2\n");
  // Note that there is no longer a callback attached here, so it will
  // run forever.
  g_main_loop_run(loop2);
  g_main_loop_unref(loop2);
  loop2 = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```