# g_main_loop_run blocks the Qthread and does not allow to stop video

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, gstreamer, qthread

I have created a separate class for gstreamer to stream videos.
This class runs on separate thread by using moveToThread().
I am using Qt5.5 for development.
When I issue startcommand on main thread , Qthread starts and gstreamer uses `g_main_loop_run` to stream videos. This works absolutely fine. But somehow `g_main_loop_run` blocks the thread and when I issue signal to stop video from main thread , it doesnt execute slot in gstreamer class.

Can someone please advice me how to resolve that issue? Either I can replace `g_main_loop_r`un with someother command or may be use `g_main_loop_quit( gloop )`; in another way.

```
void StreamingVideo::slotStartStream() // this slot called on start of thread from main thread
{

    if( !isElementsLinked() )
    {
       qDebug() << " we are emitting in dummy server ";
        //emit sigFailed( "elementsFailed" ); // WILL CONNECT IT WITH MAIN GUI ONXCE CODE IS FINISHED
        return;
    }

    gst_bus_add_watch( bus, busCall, gloop );
    gst_object_unref( bus );

    //proper adding to pipe
    gst_bin_add_many( GST_BIN( pipeline ), source, capsFilter, conv, videoRate, capsFilterRate,
                      clockDisplay, videoEnc, udpSink, NULL
                     );

    //proper linking:
    gst_element_link_many( source, capsFilter, conv, videoRate, capsFilterRate, clockDisplay, videoEnc, udpSink, NULL );

    g_print("Linked all the Elements together\n");
    gst_element_set_state( pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING );
    // Iterate
    g_print ("Running...\n");
    emit sigStartStream(); // signal to main thread to issue success command . works fine
    g_main_loop_run( gloop );
    g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
    //gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    if( g_main_loop_is_running( gloop ) )
    {
        qDebug() << " in g_main_loop_is_runnung  emiting signal ";
        emit sigStartStream();
    }
    if( !g_main_loop_is_running( gloop) )
    {
        qDebug() << "in not gmain running thread id";
        qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }

}



void StreamingVideo::slotStopStream() // THIS SLOT IS NOT CALLED WHEN VIDEO RUNNING
{
    qDebug() << " we are planning to stop streaming  stramingVideo::slotStopStream ";
    g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
    g_main_loop_quit( gloop );
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
   // g_main_loop_quit( gloop );
    releaseMemory();
    emit sigStopStream(); // signal to main thread to issue message saying video has stopped.
}
```

// somewhere in main thread

```
 threadStreaming = new QThread();
 streamVideo    = new StreamingVideo( "127.0.0.1"); // we will automate this ip address later on

        streamVideo->moveToThread( threadStreaming );

        connect( threadStreaming, SIGNAL( started() ),        streamVideo,     SLOT( slotStartStream() ) );
        connect( streamVideo,     SIGNAL( sigStopStream() ),  threadStreaming, SLOT( quit() ) );
        connect( streamVideo,     SIGNAL( sigStopStream() ),  streamVideo,     SLOT(deleteLater() ) );
        connect( threadStreaming, SIGNAL( finished() ),       threadStreaming, SLOT(deleteLater() ) );

        connect( streamVideo,     SIGNAL( sigStartStream() ), this, SLOT( slotTrueStreamRun()  ) );
        connect( streamVideo,     SIGNAL( sigStopStream() ),  this, SLOT( slotFalseStreamRun() ) );

        connect( this,            SIGNAL( sigMopsCamStopCmd() ), streamVideo, SLOT(slotStopStream() ) );
        threadStreaming->start();
```

Comment: Why not just use QMediaPlayer instead of trying to cobble together Qt and Gtk+?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's req of project to use only gstreamer-0.10 n with qt. Lol

Comment: So you can't use gstreamer without g_main_loop_run?

Comment: In a proper design, you should not have to kill the thread, the event loop, whatever will be, will have some way of terminating, even if you don't have async/queued communication between threads. You can for example use an atomic integer, and check that on every loop iteration, which you can set from the main thread so the streaming thread exits its loop.

Comment: @ddriver, the problem is once g_main_loop _run start executing it consumes all resources so even if check or send signal it wont able to execute

Comment: @samprat - can't you write your own loop and use it as g_main_loop_run?

Comment: @ddriver , I didnt get? I am using  gstreamer api g_main_loop_run to stream video byusing seperate threads

Comment: @samprat - I haven't used gstreamer, but usually users are allowed to spin their own event loops.

Comment: 1. It's a bad idea to use Qt and GTK together.
2. As far as I understand, `g_main_loop_run(gloop)` blocks exchange messages and therefore queued signal-slot connections are also blocked. 3. I think you need not to use GTK and either write your own cycle either use Qt's multimedia classes

Comment: @samprat, If you found the solution, could you post your solution at here ? I also want to run a glib main loop in a QThread.

Comment: @shang12, Sorry mate , I did it long time back and I cant remember now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to rely on a`GMainLoop`. The pipeline should run just fine without a `g_main_loop_run()`.

The one thing you have to note here is that your main Qt application loop will either have to poll the pipeline's bus for messages OR use `gst_bus_set_sync_handler` to set a callback function for the bus to be called as messages arrive. For the later you have to be aware that this function is then called from the pipeline's thread and not the application's one. Emitting signals here should be fine though.

If you want to go the thread way you would have to manually create a thread in your application which runs the `GMainLoop`. Also possible - the above looks like the easier and cleaner way to me though.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about GLib/GTK but what I quickly googled -- some inspiration came from this SO post [add callback for separate g_main_loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410585/add-callback-for-separate-g-main-loop) and the docu at https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add

The thing is that you are dealing with two event loops -- the Qt event loop for the thread, which is implicitly entered inside `QThread::run ()`, and the GLib loop, which you enter manually inside your `slotStartStream ()`. All Qt signals you send from the main thread have to go through the Qt dispatcher -- so you have to give Qt some chance to process them, and that means that the GLib loop needs to hand over control to Qt periodically. So the idea is: install a callback (e.g. a simple timer) that GLib will call periodically, and from that callback issue a `processEvents ()` function for Qt to do its job.

I would try something like that:

```
gboolean myCallback (gpointer user_data)
{
  // The Qt thread is passed as a parameter during callback installation

  QThread* workerThread = reinterpret_cast<QThread*> (user_data);

  // Access the Qt thread's event dispatcher...

  QAbstractEventDispatcher* disp = workerThread->eventDispatcher ();

  // ...and let it do its work

  disp->processEvents (QEventLoop::AllEvents);

  return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}

void StreamingVideo::slotStartStream ()
{
  [...]

  g_print ("Running...\n");

  // Install callback to intertwine Qt's thread-local eventloop with our GLib loop
  g_timeout_add (50, myCallback, QThread::currentThread ());

  emit sigStartStream(); // signal to main thread to issue success command . works fine

  g_main_loop_run( gloop );
  g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");

  [...]
```

Now, I don't know if that solves all your problems (in fact I'm pretty sure it doesn't :-)), but I think you will at least see that your `slotStopStream ()` will in fact be called (in the scope of the worker thread) after those modifications.

All in all, it's a rather hellish setup, but it might just work.

Comment: Actually , after modification to my code , It goes inside slotStopStream but after executing g_main_loop_quit , the video still does not stop

Answer (score 0):

There is no need on using glib's GMainLoop inside a Qt application. Qt has it's own version of GMainLoop (QEventLoop) which you can just think of as the exec() method.

For example, if you have a QGuiApplication class/derived class, you can call its exec() method to start its main event loop.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#exec

Similarly, if you have a QThread class/derived class, you can call its exec() method to start its local event loop.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exec

Summary, any glib code that needs an event loop to trigger its process (e.g. g_bus_own_name, in glib you need to call GMainLoop in order for the dbus to start. If you put this in a Qt code, you only need to call exec() instead of dealing with GMainLoop.

To make long story short, there is only one event loop but different implementations are made by different organization (e.g. gnome, qt)

Comment: This don't work, without GMainLoop, you cannot accept signal from gstreamer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the OP for raising an important question of GLib/Qt interop, which is insufficiently covered on the Internet. This is how `GMainLoop` works in a `QThread` for me:

```
QObject context;
QThread thread;
void* arvMainLoop;

...

context.moveToThread(&thread);
QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::started, &context, [&]()
{
    GMainLoop* loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    arvMainLoop = reinterpret_cast<void*>(loop);

    GMainContext* context = g_main_loop_get_context(loop);

    // TODO Maybe make interruption checks less frequent here.
    while (!thread.isInterruptionRequested())
        g_main_context_iteration(context, FALSE);

    g_main_loop_quit(loop);
});

thread.start();

...

thread.requestInterruption();
thread.quit();
thread.wait();

GMainLoop* loop = reinterpret_cast<GMainLoop*>(arvMainLoop);
g_main_loop_unref(loop);
```